# Adding wp_head() in wordpress header makes everything in body disappear

Tags: php, wordpress

I am starting with wordpress and after adding dynamic heading `<?php wp_head(); ?>` everything in the `body` disappears.

this is my header.php file

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
   <head>
   <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset');?>">
   <title><?php bloginfo('name');?> | <?php wp_title();?></title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <link href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">
   <?php wp_head(); ?>
  </head>
```

When I remove the `<?php wp_head(); ?>` line, everything in the body shows. I am told that including the line is a must in wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

On your `header.php` you have to call:

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

On your internal pages, like `index.php` you have to call:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
```

See:https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Also you can turn your debug mode on in order to identify the errors.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress